# Не получается получить текст из картинки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу разгадать эту капчу, `tensorflow` нет (через `pip` не устанавливается).
Я пробовал разгадывать через `pytesseract`, в ответ же я ничего не получаю. Как я могу разгадать эту капчу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить версию питона 3.8 или 3.6. Мне это помогло поставить тензорфлоу. Остальное можно найти в открытом доступе, программ написано немало.